# Wodpress: One click demo install

Tags: wordpress, redux

Приветствую!

Заканчиваю разработку своей темы под wordpress для последующего размещения на themeforest.

Очень хочу реализовать импорт данных (посты, страницы, виджеты) wordpress + данные опций темы.

Опции формирую через Redux Framework.

Хотел бы обойтись без плагинов. Устроит как готовая библиотека/класс, так и ссылки в сторону чего копать.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Я победил.
Решение вопроса: WBC_Importer Extension

Найти можно на гите: [клик](https://github.com/Webcreations907/WBC-Importer-extension)

Работает как надо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.